# mousekeys keep restting and skipping

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xbindkeys

I've just discovered mousekeys and they are a godsend for my rsi problems, but i keep having this annoying problem where occasionally while interacting with some sort of UI they reset the amount that they "skip." so instead of moving in small increments, they'll suddenly start moving in increments of an inch or two and i have to just reset their initial values.

i cannot for the life of me find anyone else who has this problem, but surely I'm not the only one??? anyone else have this experience or any pointers ( no pun intended! )?

here is what I set:

```
xkbset ma 60 10 10 15 2
xkbset exp =m
```

thanks for any help or suggestions!

am using Ubuntu 16.04, but have also had this issue on Debian Jessie

Comment: Same. You ever found a solution?

Comment: Hmmm I no longer have this problem, but I don't really know what I must have done to fix it. I swapped to using the i3 window manager, so it is possible that that had something to do with it? my current script looks like `xkbset m xkbset ma 60 10 10 25 26 xkbset exp =m`

Comment: hmm, not sure then. the output of `xkbset q` gives me the following if it's of any use:  Audible Bell = On
Repeat Keys = On
Repeat Delay = 500
Repeat Interval = 30
Per Key Repeat =
        00ffffffdffffbbf
        fadfffefffedffff
        9fffffffffffffff
        fff7ffffffffffff
Mouse-Keys = On
Mouse-Keys Default Button = 1
Mouse-Keys Acceleration = On
Mouse-Keys Acceleration Delay = 60
Mouse-Keys Acceleration Interval = 10
Mouse-Keys Acceleration Time to Max = 10
Mouse-Keys Acceleration Max Speed = 19
Mouse-Keys Acceleration Curve = 2
Accessibility Features (AccessX)=Off

Comment: Sticky-Keys = Off
Two Keys Mask = On
Latch to Lock Mask = On
Slow-Keys = Off
Slow Keys Delay = 300
Bounce-Keys = Off
Debounce Delay = 300
AccessX Feedback = On
Use Fixed Pitch Bell = On
Beep when LED changes = Off
Beep on Controls on/off = On
Beep if Slow/Bounce-Keys about to be turned off = On
Beep on Slow-Key Press = On
Beep on Slow-Key Accept = On
Beep on Slow-Key Reject = Off
Beep on Slow-Key Release = Off
Beep on Bounce-Key Reject = On
Beep on Sticky-Key Actions = On
Keyboard Overlay 1 = Off
Keyboard Overlay 2 = Off
Groups Wrap Type = wrap
Groups Wrap Value = 1

Comment: Ignore Group Lock = On
Nullify Shift = Off
Nullify Caps-Lock = Off
Nullify Control = Off
Nullify Mod1 = Off
Nullify Mod2 = Off
Nullify Mod3 = Off
Nullify Mod4 = Off
Nullify Mod5 = Off
Ignore Lock of Shift = Off
Ignore Lock of Caps-Lock = Off
Ignore Lock of Control = Off
Ignore Lock of Mod1 = Off
Ignore Lock of Mod2 = Off
Ignore Lock of Mod3 = Off
Ignore Lock of Mod4 = Off
Ignore Lock of Mod5 = Off